2021 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #1 on Bricks has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are... the same team you've already had!



Please thank them for volunteering and congratulate them for being re-elected as moderators!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Thank you to everyone who voted, and thank you Zovits for putting yourself forward as well. I certainly appreciate the vote of confidence that you think we're doing a good job for you all, and I hope we can continue to do so :)

Thank you for continuing the amazing job you have been doing all this time! I kind of knew my application was pointless as soon as the three of you have submitted yours :)

@zovits - it's never pointless to run, I've stood in other elections to ensure that the "expected" candidate did have to run a proper campaign and wasn't a shoe-in (although those also had a "re-open nominations" option on the ballot).
